# How to have multiple crontab entries for different projects Laravel task scheduling?

Tags: laravel, cron

I am using Laravel and am working with scheduling tasks. It is working fine in one project, but I want to use it in another as well. How would I add the crontab entry needed? Here is what my crontab file looks like for my first project:

```
* * * * * cd ~/code/project1; /usr/local/bin/php && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Here is how I've tried to add the second project:

```
* * * * * cd ~/code/project1; /usr/local/bin/php && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
* * * * * cd ~/code/project2; /usr/local/bin/php && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

and

```
* * * * * cd ~/code/project1; /usr/local/bin/php && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1,
* * * * * cd ~/code/project2; /usr/local/bin/php && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

But neither of these have worked. How would I successfully edit my crontab file for running this command on multiple projects?

Comment: Why not just reference each project's artisan file? like `/usr/local/bin/php && php ~/code/project1/artisan ...`

Comment: Not exactly sure how you mean I should accomplish this. The problem is not with the artisan command, but with attempting to run the artisan command for different projects.

Comment: Each Laravel project has an `artisan` file, so reference it absolutely in your `CRON` signature: `* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php && php ~/code/project2/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`; You shouldn't need the `cd` command

Comment: But this still doesn't solve referencing multiple projects.. Separating each project with `&&` only works for the last project referenced.

Comment: Doesn't each line in a CRON tab run independently? If you have a line for every project, referencing their individual artisan file, doesn't that solve this? Maybe I don't know enough about CRON.

Comment: Yeah, looking at one of my server's CRON tabs, that hosts multiple Laravel files, I can see `* * * * * php /absolute/path/to/project/artisan schedule:run` listed for each Project, and all of the schedules run with no issue. None of mine have a `,` at the end of them though; they're their own individual entries.

Comment: Ahh okay that seems to work. I don't know too much about CRON either. But, if each line does run independently, why didn't the first solution I tried work?

Comment: The only thing I can see that might cause an issue is that trailing `,` on your tab. It's not there in the first attempt, so I'm not 100% sure. At least you got it working though!

Comment: Yes true! It's just frustrating when something that seemingly should work does not. But thank you!

Comment: I hear you :) And it's always the smallest things too. Cheers!